# Stop emacs from redrawing display

Tags: terminal-emacs

[image]

I'm using emacs from a terminal, and have noticed that certain commands make the terminal screen flicker when I use them.

Notable commands are evil mode's `recenter-top-bottom` and `xref-find-definitions`

This must surely be possible, as `xref-pop-marker-stack`, a command that has a very similar function as `xref-find-definitions`, does not have this issue. The whole terminal is not updated and doesn't give a flicker.

Is there any way of stopping this from happening? The flicker is quite annoying. This only appears to happen when emacs is run inside of a terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure 'bout `xref-find-definition`m but for `recenter-top-bottom`, I think you simply need

```
(setq recenter-redisplay nil)
```

Comment: This fixed worked for both commands! Thank you.